# ERROR: Provided address "6.963865902119903e+47" is invalid

Tags: web3js, metamask, json-rpc

Full error log:

```
formatters.js:471 Uncaught Error: Provided address "6.963865902119903e+47" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.
at Object.inputAddressFormatter (formatters.js:471)
at Object.set [as address] (index.js:92)
at Contract (index.js:296)
at new Contract (index.js:273)
at index.html:23
```

I get this error when I try to run index.html in my Chrome browser. I expect it has something to do with the fact that this code is copied from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0vhvBHd4Ro) tutorial which is about 1.5 years old.

[Here](https://github.com/Lennardmulder/soltodapp) is my directory

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had forgotten to put the contract's instance address in quotes!

See last line of this snippet:

```
var ethereumSessionInstance = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_myInt",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setTheInt",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getTheInt",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_myInt",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
], "0x79fB0E00F4dB8812b04Ae84816BbccAF941E5c90");
```

The error was solved by putting quotes around the address.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the type of `0x79fB0E00F4dB8812b04Ae84816BbccAF941E5c90` is `Number`.

Yet, the value of this number is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is 53 bits long.

Solidity address types are 160 bits long, and they are passed to/from web3.js functions as strings.

Hence, you should always use quotes around any address value in your Javascript code.